# jQuery $(this) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to here is on hover, the div id magnify has a small animation - the animation is working - however it's not working more than one div at a time. Looking for a little guidance if I did this incorrect by chance.

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#project-holder").hover(function(){
    $(".client"+$(this).attr("client")).stop().animate({'margin-left': '130px', 'margin-top': '80px'}, 500);
  }, function(){
    $(".client"+$(this).attr("client")).stop().animate({'margin-left': '-200px'}, 500);
  });
});
</script>
```

an example of the div is:

```
<div id="project-holder" client="1">
  <div id="magnify" class="client1">
    <img src="magnify.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements that have an id of `project-holder`?

Comment: @Blender great question.  To expand on what he's asking, an ID must be unique.  Target on a class insetad to get multiple project-holders wired up with your hover handler.

Comment: A jsfiddle of this would be useful. www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your HTML to use classes instead. Ids are unique and the same id cannot be used more than once:

```
<div class="project-holder">
  <div class="magnify client">
    <img src="magnify.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, you can change your JS to this and it should work just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".project-holder").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.client').stop().animate({'margin-left': '130px', 'margin-top': '80px'}, 500);
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.client').stop().animate({'margin-left': '-200px'}, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: That's embaressing. That's for pointing that out. Works perfect now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working for more than one at a time because the `$(this)` selector refers to a unique element, not a class or multiple ids. You need to use `each()` to go through all the divs one at a time. Also, you shouldn't use the same id twice - give them a class instead and use `each()` to iterate through each div, applying the code you want.